# Не тот язык пять раз проверь?

Tags: предложение, закрытие-вопросов, причины-закрытия, переоткрытие-вопросов

Действительно ли надо 5 человек, чтобы подтвердить, что вопрос задан не на том языке?
А потом ещё 5, чтобы подтвердить, что его перевели на русский?

Предлагаю для причины закрытия

> Вопрос закрыт, так как на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

сделать закрытие одним голосом. И переоткрытие с неё тоже одним голосом.

Comment: Хотя бы 2 или 3 тогда, иначе можно будет любой вопрос закрыть единолично (хотя и переоткрыть тоже единолично). Будут этакие войны закрытий-открытий.

Comment: @insolor, ну за закрытие вопроса на русском как вопроса на английском надо ставить тревогу и наказывать...

Comment: @insolor _"Будут этакие войны закрытий-открытий."_ o_O "Этот вопрос на английском!" - "Нет, он на русском!" - "Да вы что? На английском!" - "А я тоже считаю, что на русском!" - поржал)))

Comment: С одной стороны да, за ложное закрытие можно (нужно) будет банить, но лучше просто не давать возможности злоупотребления. В целом я согласен, что 5 голосов для закрытия по причине "не тот язык" это много, но и закрытие 1 голосом - это слишком мало, IMHO.

Comment: @insolor, хм.. а вообще я тут про всякие белорусские и украинские подумал - не уверен, что их стоит так закрывать...

Comment: @Qwertiy они всё равно подлежат переводу. Так что стоит, однозначно. Или переводить собственноручно за ТСа, что не порицается, но и в обязанности сообщества не входит.

Answer (score 5):

Насколько я понимаю, частная причина закрытия off-topic из-за нерусского языка с помощью единственной радио-кнопки особо ничем не отличается от причины вида "другое", где нужно самостоятельно ввести текст. Таким образом задать для нее иное кол-во голосов вряд ли возможно в настройках сайта. К тому же, даже такие, на первый взгляд, очевидные ситуации, как иной язык, не должны разрешать закрывать вопрос единолично. В моменты отсутствия модератора закрытие должно проводиться исключительно коллегиально. Хотя можно было бы предусмотреть и некоторые веса голосов в зависимости от опыта. Но это уже совсем другая история. В текущей ситуации предложение скорее всего получит метку [статус-отклонено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be), если кто-то вообще решится из русскоговорящих бубновых участников её поставить.

Comment: Намекаете что кто-то нетолерантно относится к русскоговорящим?

Comment: @Aid с чего Вы так решили?

Answer (score 5):

Прекрасное предложение. Если кому не по душе, то дайте хотя бы такую возможность дадим пользователям после определённого уровня репутации или для человека с золотым значком по данной метке вопроса (например, [c#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), [c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), [php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) и т.д.) по аналогии с функционалом дубликата. Зачем зря тратить время пяти человек и засорять очередь проверок такой банальщиной?

Comment: Золото имеет значение при теме сообщения. А для того, чтобы понять что язык не тот, достаточно школьного аттестата; золото ни к чему.

Comment: @Aid Это понятно, но может так будет проще реализовать (по аналогии с дубликатами). Лучше хоть так, чем никак.

Comment: Сомневаюсь что кто-то из разрабов сделает подобное, слишком опасно выдавать такие права.