# Автоматическое определение вопросов не на русском языке

Tags: предложение, закрытие-вопросов

Навеяно [этим вопросом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5509/227016).

Предлагаю добавить проверку при задании вопроса, а именно: если ни заголовок, ни тело вопроса не содержат ни одного русского символа, то не разрешать задавать вопрос и показывать какое-нибудь уведомление об этом.

Мне кажется, что такая проверка позволит убрать почти все вопросы на английском. Также я не могу придумать вопрос на русском, который бы эта проверка помешала задать.

Comment: Просто и гениально, как никто раньше не догадался.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian ne ushemit li eto prava obladateley Latin-only klaviatur?

Comment: @alexolut язык разве не на уровне OS работает? Даже если предположить какую-то ограниченную в возможностях операционку, вероятно этот сайт так или иначе на ней бы хромал.

Comment: Достаточно часто встречаю вопросы, в которых топикстартер поленился и в теле вопроса только код. В подобных ситуациях будет повышенное число ложных срабатываний: надежда только на наличие комментариев на русском языке и на то, что в заголовке есть кириллица, а не набор ключевых слов на английском языке.

Comment: @AK лень должна быть наказана!

Comment: Возможно стоит не проверку делать, а написать бота, типа smoke detector, что уже пасётся в чате?

Comment: @AK если бы бот мог закрывать такие вопросы, то да. Но он же не сможет. А дополнительно уведомлять о них смысла нет, они и так быстро закрываются, ну или переводятся на русский. Идея не допускать создания подобных вопросов куда симпатичнее.

Comment: Возможно, если подключить парсер Markdown, то можно проверить, не состоит ли _текстовая_ часть вопроса из одной лишь латиницы. Если текстовая часть пустая, то сообщение должно быть другим («плохое качество вопроса»).