# Возможная причина появления на ruSO вопросов на английском

Tags: обсуждение

Я кажется нашел одну из причин появления на ruSO вопросов, заданных на английском. Заключается она вот в таком баннере на enSO:

> [image: баннер]

То есть человек ходит-бродит по англоязычному сайту и тут ему предлагаю задать вопрос. Хотя текст и понятен, далеко не сразу становится очевидно, что и задавать вопрос нужно именно на русском языке. Вполне можно предположить что это всего лишь какой-то автоперевод контента (нечто похожее можно встречать на msdn).

Кто что думает на этот счёт? Разумна ли моя теория, и если да, можно ли здесь что-то улучшить, дабы вопрос на ruSO задавался именно на русском языке?

Comment: Ломаю голову над причинами подобных вопросов уже давно. Идея похожа на правильную, но вообще логичнее задавать вопрос каждому, кто пишет на ru so вопросы на английском в комментариях. Здесь улучшить можно (явно написать про русский язык), но я бы сначала попроверял гипотезу, поспрашивав в очередях проверки, почему они задали вопрос на русском.

Comment: Чтобы вопрос на ruSO задавался именно на русском языке можно требовать [наличие русского текста в вопросе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5521/227016) :)

Comment: @diraria уже давно заплюсовано :)

Comment: Это не теория, а гипотеза

Comment: А разве этот текст показывается не только пользователям с российскими IP?

Comment: @Byulent а что это меняет?

Comment: @Byulent упоминалось опознание по заголовку `Accept-Language` браузера, который связан с настройками браузера и ОС. Что довольно надёжный показатель того, что читающий владеет русским языком: если на чтение интерфейса хватает знания языка (работает для всего, кроме английского, т. к. он по умолчанию).

Answer (score 11):

Как мне кажется, проблема может быть иной (как минимум, я вижу в этом проблему): если вы незарегистрированный пользователь, в верхней части сайта вы видите следующий баннер.

[image: баннер]

Как вы можете заметить, снимок сделан с сайта Stack Overflow на английском, при этом баннер на русском языке, более того, при клике он ведет на регистрацию на Stack Overflow на русском!

Ситуация крайне неоднозначная. Теоретически:

1. Баннер показывается только людям с русским языком в обозревателе или с IP русскоговорящих стран.
2. Когда человек регистрируется и (!) задает вопрос, уже на Stack Overflow на русском, интерфейс сайта однозначно говорит о языке сообщества (хотя, тут вопрос спорный, возможно, люди воспринимают данный факт как локализацию самого продукта, а не сообщества).

Лично я не до конца позитивно отношусь к этой инициативе в текущем виде (да–да, она не моя!), хотя, как мы видим, если догадка верна, кто–то все–таки приходит к нам в сообщество по этому баннеру.

#### Что можно сделать?

1. Оставить все как есть: «работает – не трогай»! Имеем то, что имеем и дальше живем с этим.
2. Лично я бы, сделал одно из двух:

   1. (*Просто*) Убрал бы баннер ведущий на Stack Overflow на русском c англоязычного сайта вовсе.
   2. (*Сложнее*) Изменил бы текст (добавил явное упоминание наличия русскоязычного и англоязычного сообщества) и сделал бы две кнопки: (а) зарегистрироваться на Stack Overflow на английском, (б) зарегистрироваться на Stack Overflow на русском.
3. (Предложено @D-side) Поменять баннер. Явно указать о наличии двух разных сообществ, предложив (1) зарегистрироваться на англоязычном или (2) перейти на главную Stack Overflow на русском.

Буду крайне рад отзывам и рекомендациям по пункту 2. Уверен, вместе мы сможем найти более качественное решение сложившейся ситуации!

Comment: Предлагаю (3): (а) зарегистрироваться на en.SO, (б) **перейти** на ru.SO (а ссылку на регистрацию здесь разместить уже здесь).

Comment: @D-side Пожалуйста, опишите вашу идею развернуто. Мне кажется, я ее не до конца понял.

Comment: Как п. 2.2, но *вместо кнопки регистрации* на ru.SO *кнопка перехода на главную* ru.SO, где уже есть свой баннер для новоприбывших (есть же? я не проверял).

Comment: @D-side Спасибо! Идею понял!

Comment: (4): упразднить en.SO и прочие не русскоязычные сайты.

Comment: @alexolut Это не выход потому что это никак не содействует решению проблемы.

Comment: Всегда ли проблемный вопрос - первый у участника? Не задавал ли он до этого вопросов на enSO. Надо посмотреть по списку закрытых и требующих перевода. Вы можете такую выборку сформировать?

Comment: @alexolut Думаю, средствами SEDE это может сделать любой, примерно с одинаковым успехом. Правда, есть некоторые ограничения – не уверен, что можно сделать запрос по нескольким сайтам одновременно.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky частную причину закрытия-то вытащить? А кто у нас вообще в SEDE шпарит?

Comment: @alexolut Пожалуйста, поясните про причину закрытия. SEDE – это просто база данных, так что любой, знающий SQL.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky насколько я помню, Вы добавляли частную причину закрытия "не русский язык сообщения". Можно ли вытащить именно вопросы, закрытые по этой причине?

Comment: @alexolut Хм, я думаю, что как–то это сделать можно.

Comment: Сколько действительных вопросов на английском было задана на Stack Overflow на русском? Сколько из этих вопросов были заданы после перехода по ссылке в баннере? Иначе говоря, а существует ли проблема вообще?

Comment: @jfs проблема определённо существует, кнопка в контексте означает для пользователей одно, а делает совсем другое. Связана ли эта проблема с обсуждаемой в этом вопросе -- вопрос хороший. Но не уверен, что по нему возможно собрать доказательную статистику, т. к. момент упущен, а собирать новую статистику дело небыстрое и может потребовать вмешательства разработчиков. Но решить проблему из ответа стоит независимо от этого.

Answer (score 7):

Просто в следующий раз, встретив такой вопрос, спросите в комментариях у автора: почему он решил написать на русском сайте сообщение по-английски. Так можно узнать причину оного поведения.

Впрочем этот же трюк можно провести и со старыми (закрытыми) сообщениями на английском, задав их авторам аналогичный вопрос в чате.

Так у вас на руках будут факты, а не только лишь догадки и предположения.

Comment: Такая идея уже [озвучивалась в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39919543#39919543) @AK. С некоторым продолжением. В общем, почитайте.

Comment: Отвечали: "сайт перепутал".

Answer (score 6):

Мне кажется, можно выводить предупреждение в случае всего текста на английском.

Когда я перешла на руссокоязычную версию stackoverflow из поисковика по ключевому слову stackoverflow (я набирала просто stack, но это не важно) мне даже в голову не пришло, что это для русского языка. Я решила, что это очередная попытка предоставить интерфейс на языке страны, в которой я нахожусь. Хотя если бы я внимательно читала весь текст страницы я бы поняла.  Но кто же читает *весь* текст сайтов...

Поэтому предлаю выводить предупреждение пользователю об отсутствии русского языка в его вопросе.

Comment: Агась. [Уже предложено](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5521/181100).

Comment: @D-side, понимаю, но ссылка вопроса, который меня спросили, велась на эту страницу.

Comment: @Irina ваше мнение важно для нас. Спасибо!