# Можно ли добавить проверку на наличие кириллицы при публикации вопроса?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

**Предложение:** перед публикацией вопроса проверять, есть ли в тексте вопроса хотя бы один символ кириллицы. Если кириллицы нет, то запрещать публиковать вопрос и выводить сообщение на двух языках с предложением либо вернуться на большой Stack Overflow, либо перевести вопрос.

Уже есть такого рода предпроверки на плохо отформатированный код и на длину сообщения. Полагаю, что будет несложно добавить еще одну, вроде:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Думаю, что это поможет новым пользователям задать корректный вопрос на нужном им сайте. Также это сэкономит ресурсы сообщества по закрыванию/открыванию/переводу вопросов.

Насколько я понимаю такая проверка не должна помешать нормальному использованию сайта. В вырожденных случаях, когда и заголовок и текст вопроса состоят из кода/сообщений об ошибках автору будет полезно и несложно добавить пару строк поясняющего текста.

**Контекст:** Новые пользователи часто публикуют вопросы на английском. Как правило такие вопросы за несколько минут набирают минуса и закрываются [по специально для этой цели созданной причине](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4091/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B5). После этого либо автор выправляет свой вопрос, либо пропадает с концами и закрытый вопрос удаляется по таймауту, либо (наихудший вариант) вопрос закрывается как дубликат вопроса на русском языке и остается без перевода.

Примеры:

- [Application with Ethereum Smart Contracts [закрыт]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/808875/application-with-ethereum-smart-contracts)
- [DROP Existing Local DataBase C# SQL [дубликат]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/428759/drop-existing-local-database-c-sql)

Есть мнение, что часть таких пользователей пытается задать вопрос на англоязычной версии Stack Overflow и не замечают перенаправления на русскоязычную. Это обсуждалось в теме: «[Возможная причина появления на ruSO вопросов на английском](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5872/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-ruso-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC)».

[Запрос на Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/837612/questions-without-cyrillic-characters) находит 69 таких вопросов, т.к. большая часть непереведенных вопросов уже удалена и недоступна. Среди приведенных вопросов есть незакрытые, но по‑моему все они требуют либо закрытия/удаления, либо существенного улучшения. Например, самые старые из них:

- [Python in Linux Ubuntu](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/117892/python-in-linux-ubuntu)
- [Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource [дубликат]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/129808/warning-mysql-fetch-assoc-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource)
- [Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by [дубликат]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/130045/warning-cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent-by)

К своему удивлению не нашел подобного предложения на Мете.

Comment: @alexolut Спасибо! Искал такой вопрос по слову «кириллица» и не нашел.

Comment: Кстати, уведомления о комментарии я не получил, т.к. надо было сначала написать комментарий, а потом согласиться с дубликатом (это действие удаляет мой автосгенерированный комментарий).

Comment: @alexolut Да, как то упустил этот момент.