# Давайте добавим проверку на английское тело вопроса?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, вопросы

Появилась идея, не факт что хорошая, но решил вынести на всеобщее обсуждение. У нас есть на сайте возможность публикации нового вопроса - очевидный факт. Но лично меня начинает немного напрягать кол-во вопросов, которые публикуются на английском языке. Либо люди на автомате сюда пишут на англ языке, либо чего-то не понимают. Поэтому у меня есть предложение - пусть пользователь сам выполняет проверку своего вопроса. Сейчас постараюсь объяснить в чем суть, но не бейте сильно так как в веб разработке я довольно слабо разбираюсь и могу что-то не так сказать.

На enSO при написании нового вопроса есть небольшая проверка на наличие неформатированного кода в теле вопроса, и пока в нем есть такого плана код, то юзеру будет об этом говорится. Я бы предложил добавить подобного рода проверку, но немного доработанную. Было бы неплохо проверять поле для ввода вопроса на наличие англ букв, и если они есть то как-то об этом говорить пользователю. Но я думаю большинство сейчас задастся вопросом - а как же код? И это очевидный вопрос, так как код пишется на англ языке. И вот тут можно прикрутить заодно и напоминание о форматировании кода. Чтобы проверка обходила блоки кода и проверяла только текст за пределами таких блоков. Вот например пользователь пишет вопрос, сам вопрос на русском а код неформатированный. Соответственно проверка говорит что-то типа: "Проверьте ваш вопрос на наличие неформатированного кода, и если он есть то выделите его и нажмите на кнопочку {}." Если пользователь провел все манипуляции правильно, то все должно сработать и вопрос выйдет в свет.

Я не спорю, возможно идея хрень и не заслуживает реализации, но было бы интересно услышать общественное мнение :)

Comment: Идея хорошая. Реализовано вряд ли будет в силу того, что нужно лишь локализованным сайтам.

Comment: Предложение, похожее на первую часть: [Автоматическое определение вопросов не на русском языке](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5521/%d0%90%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b5) Наличие латинских символов не проблема (Java, Python и т.п.), можно проверять на отсутствие кириллицы.

Comment: @defaultlocale, да идея одна и та же :)

Comment: Мне кажется, проблему проще решить на более ранней стадии -- при перенаправлении сюда участников желающих задать вопрос на enSO. Почему для них не очевиден тот факт, что они оказались на лоализованном сайте? Может это написано для них маленькими буквами?

Comment: @0xdb, тогда проще баннер повесить побольше))

Comment: @Andrew Ага, это и имею ввиду, и лучше поп-ап  с кнопкой "Я понял".

Comment: @Andrew: ну... баннер баннером, а российский гимн фончиком включить не лишним будет ;-)

Comment: @Miron, термины я думаю можно тоже выделять в скобки кода, будет выделение какое-то хоть чтобы не терялось на фоне текста :)

Comment: Тогда проще сделать следующую проверку - если в вопросе нет ни одного русского символа, то выводить предупреждение.

Comment: а не проще бороться с русским?)) пусть люди английский учат))

Comment: @PaulWall, идея конечно интересная, но уже даже целый сайт придумали для этого))

Answer (score 20):

Проверять наоборот - в вопросе есть хотя бы десяток русских букв (в любом месте - считаютя и заголовок, и тело).

Answer (score 2):

Проверка на наличие или отсутствие в тексте кириллических символов не поможет, так как они используются в письменности и других языков, кроме русского.

Comment: Отличить украинский от русского будет сложно, но английский отсеять так всё-таки можно.

Comment: Другие тоже можно задетектить: `ү` в монгольском например

Comment: @Кирилл Малышев украинский: `i`.

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica `i` может встречаться в корректном тексте, а потому не может служить маркером.

Comment: `"і" == "i"
False`

Comment: Русский не так и сложно отличить от украинского. Украинское `i` отличается от английского, это разные символы. Также в украинском есть `ї`, `ґ` и `є`. В украинском нет `ы`, `э`, `ё`, `ъ`.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov во-первых, я не только про украинский. Во-вторых, я видел немало украинских текстов набранных только русским алфавитом.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Я тут видел чистый украинский текст, его бы смог этот способ отфильтровать.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, а на каких языках сюда ещё пишут? Я только украинский и английский видел.

Comment: @КириллМалышев я на монгольском писал :)

Comment: @Vadim Ovchinnikov Правильно я и хотел сказать, что это разные символы: `"і" == "i" False`